# Playing Movies from ITunes using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, drm

I'm trying to play a movie acquired from iTunes. The movie was placed in my sandbox via File Sharing/iTunes Transfer. The application is using `MPMoviePlayerController` or `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I can use either, but neither have work properly on an iTunes movie.

Below is what I am observing:

- Test Movie

  - Acquired from Hillegass (Chapter 20) - OK [1]
  - Acquired from Apple's sample - OK [2]
  - Apple Video app - OK
- iTunes Movie

  - No video
  - No audio
  - Silent failure in my application [3]
  - Silent failure in Hillegass' sample [3]
  - Silent failure in Apple's sample [3]
  - Apple Video app - OK

When the view is launched, I get a black screen and the PLAY button is available. Tapping *PLAY* causes the player to attempt the operation, but it fails (?) and the PLAY button is shown again.

Checking the state of the movie controller shows it is Ready. When *PLAY* is tapped, the state goes to Playing and then immediately to paused. Trying to *PLAY* again repeats the cycle.

During the Ready → Playing → Paused transitions, I *do not* get a finished notification, and I *do not* get an error from other notifications.

I thought orientation might be the issue, but rotating or changing the orientation mode crashes Xcode.

Apple's documentation does not mention anything special for iTunes movies, protected content, or DRM (perhaps I missed a relevant document). It seems like a moot point, since the movie was purchased from iTunes, the device is authorized (all under the same account), and I am the licensee.

For what its worth, `NSZombieEnabled` is YES, so I don't believe I am smashing memory (memory errors are probably not present in Apple's and Hillegass' samples).

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong or how I should play an iTunes movie I purchased?

---

**References**

[1] http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide

[2] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

[3] http://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/tv-shows/the-simpsons/lost-verizon/

Comment: Please provide links to those movie's you tried.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController just as well as AVPlayer do not support DRM protected content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DRM protection is the problem.

**Apple does not allow playing DRM protected music or videos from iTunes in the MPMoviePlayerController (which includes the previews).**

Please also see following link on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724052/playing-m4v-protected-content-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-or-avplayer-ios)

Regarding the crash: You may post some code.

Comment: Thanks Max. You know I wasted days on that problem because Apple did not think it was important to mention the limitations and alternatives. Apple is very anti-competitive, so there are probably no alternatives. Its too bad the US Federal Trade Commission or Department of Justice won't help us...